# English word for adding "monitoring points" to a process

Tags: programming, computing

There is an English word that I can't remember about adding "monitoring points" to computer code so that when the code is run "trace" information, such as the module being executed or the values of variables at that point in the code are stored for later inspection. The monitoring/tracing does not affect the function or execution of the code. I keep on coming up with "metricate the source code" but that isn't correct and I can't get past that word.

Comment: Validation? Check points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another term is [instrumentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_(computer_programming)), "the measure of a product's performance, to diagnose errors, and to write trace information". ([Stack Exchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434516/what-is-instrumentation)). You might refer to "instrumenting" code, meaning adding diagnostic macros/functions/labels.

Comment: I think that's it

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the specific use case, consider using:

- [Tracing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_(software)): "a specialized use of logging to record information about a program's execution."
- [Profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)): "a form of dynamic program analysis that measures, for example, the space (memory) or time complexity of a program, the usage of particular instructions, or the frequency and duration of function calls."
- [Logging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logging_(software)): "[recording] either events that occur in an operating system or other software runs, or messages between different users of a communication software."

In [software debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging), specific locations where data are collected or events are fired or stopped are often called [breakpoints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakpoint).

Comment: Yes. Make sure they are all marked with a standard comment so they can be removed as a batch.